# Case Attachments on the Account Attachments Related List?

Tags: attachment, notes

I noticed that Case Attachments appear in the Account 'Notes & Attachments' section with a 'Related to' link.

However, when we have hundreds of Cases for each Account, the important Attachments that are directly related to the Account get lost.

Is there any way to hide related attachments so we only see those that were directly attached to the Account record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean "aren't directly related to the Account get lost?"  Meaning, from the Case, you want to see all of the related Account's Notes and Attachments?

If so, perhaps hide the Case Notes & Attachment, create a Visualforce page with a , and embed that into your Case Layout?

Comment: Hi Kirk, I meant that from the Account, I want to see only Attachments that have been uploaded to that record.  At the moment it also shows attachments that have been added to related cases.  So there is a list of 1,000s of attachments, most of them from Cases :/  I think a VF page would work to display only direct Account attachments (on the Account page layout), but was hoping there was a native way to filter.

Comment: There are no native ways to achieve what you are asking for. You need to create a visualforce page with controller to manage this request.